# How can I export the cognito forms resume URL for all incomplete submissions

Tags: cognito-forms

We use Cognito for a long, complex application process with application windows every 6 months. I have a large number of users that started the form and I would like to be able to email them their "resume URL" rather than have them call/email to have it manually resent. I have exported the data to excel, but I can't find a field/column that would be the resume URL. Does this exist, or alternatively can I get to t thru an API or Zapier?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

If you have [Save and Resume](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/22/building-forms/save-and-resume) enabled on your form they will be able to get an email when they first save their form. We do not have a system in place to resend the link at a later time.

You can also set up and send out a [Share Link](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/79/entries/sharing-entries) from the Entries page. This system is not automated so you will have to go in and manually generate this for the user. This will let you provide them with an edit link to pick up editing/filling out their form where they left off.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I figured, as a feature request, it would be great to have this field available in the entries export so I could mass mail reminders to people, it would greatly increase completion rates